# how to configure ajax site for googlebot?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, googlebot

I have an angular site that I have enabled html5 mode so I can have pretty urls. I need to configure the site for googlebot. What I have done so far is put this in the meta tag:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

My assumption is by placing that meta tag, I am informing googlebot that it is an ajax site and that it should append `_escaped_fragment_` in the url right inbetween domain name and the rest of the of url. For example, if it was trying to crawl http://thehaileselassie.com/Italian_Occupation, it would transform it to `http:// thehaileselassie.com/?_escaped_fragment_=Italian_Occupation`. But I don't think that is what is happening. I believe it is appending it to the end, like so: `http:// thehaileselassie.com/Italian_Occupation?_escaped_fragment_=`. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

**Extra info**

I have this in RouteConfig so all server calls are sent to HomeController:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And this is the content of the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string fragment = Request.QueryString["_escaped_fragment_"];
        if (fragment != null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fragment))
            {
                string url = "/templates/homeView.html";
                return File(Server.MapPath(url), "text/html");
            }

            else
            {
                string url = "/templates/" + fragment + ".html";
                return File(Server.MapPath(url), "text/html");
            }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`?_escaped_fragment_=` is supposed to be appended to end. What I am doing to get the part after the domain is this: `Request.Url.LocalPath`. This returns `/Italian_Occupation`. Afterwards I do some logic to create xml on the fly and return it:

```
 string url = "/templates" + Request.Url.LocalPath + ".html";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                doc.Load(Server.MapPath(url));
            }
            catch
            {
                return HttpNotFound(); 
            }


            var settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
            var propInfo = settings.GetType().GetProperty("OutputMethod");
            propInfo.SetValue(settings, System.Xml.XmlOutputMethod.Html, null);
            var stream = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);


          //  XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("book", "aaaa", "http://www.com");
          ////  doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
          //  doc.DocumentElement.(elem, doc.DocumentElement.LastChild);

            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement element1 = doc2.CreateElement(string.Empty, "html", string.Empty);
            doc2.AppendChild(element1);
            XmlElement element2 = doc2.CreateElement(string.Empty, "head", string.Empty);
            XmlElement element4 = doc2.CreateElement(string.Empty, "title", string.Empty);
            XmlText text1 = doc2.CreateTextNode("TheHaileSelassie.Com :: "+doc.GetElementsByTagName("h1")[0].InnerText);
            element4.AppendChild(text1);
            element2.AppendChild(element4);
            doc2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element2);

            XmlElement element3 = doc2.CreateElement(string.Empty, "body", string.Empty);


            XmlDocumentFragment xfrag = doc2.CreateDocumentFragment();
            xfrag.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml;
            element3.AppendChild(xfrag);
            doc2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element3);

            //doc2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xfrag);

            doc2.Save(writer);
            return Content(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(stream.ToString()));
```